# transform: scale(x,x) doesn't work on animation in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, firefox, transform

I'm trying to use a slider to "transform: scale(x,x)" a css3 "animation" in firefox.  If I turn off the animation, the slider and scaling works.  If I turn on the animation, it animates, but the scaling doesn't work.

Here is my jsfiddle...  If you uncomment the end of the CSS, you can see the problem.  I want the arrows to spin AND scale.

(FIREFOX ONLY, chrome/safari link below): http://jsfiddle.net/G6rYu/

```
$("#slider-step").on("change", function(e){
    scale= $("#slider-step").val() / 100;

    $(".elem.A").css("transform", "scale("+scale+","+scale+")");
    $(".elem.B").css("transform", "scale("+(1-scale)+","+(1-scale)+")");
});
```

and...

```
.elem.A {  
    background-image:url('http://s24.postimg.org/ua9mzwmht/arrow.png');

    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-duration: 3.0s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
 @keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(-360deg);} 
}
```

Here's the effect I'm going for (works in Chrome / Safari only): http://jsfiddle.net/nick2ny/4mLkU/

Comment: Are you sure you can use multiple transform on a single element? It should just overwrite the first `transform: scale()` when you apply `transform: rotate()`. For Chrome you use zoom so there is no conflict, I guess.

Comment: I think you're probably right.  I'm going to try that, and use webkit and no-prefix css3, and use a wrapper, like you suggested.  Then I'll optimize everything like bastien suggested.

Comment: Ta-DA! Thanks everyone.  I transformed the box wrapper...
http://jsfiddle.net/nick2ny/G6rYu/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a conflict with using transform twice on your `.elem` elements. The animation `transform: rotate()` will override `transform: scale()`. You can use a wrapper element for the scale and apply the animation to the inner element.

You seem to be using `zoom` in Chrome which can explain why it is working in that browser.

See this fiddle: **[http://jsfiddle.net/G6rYu/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/G6rYu/5/)** (for Firefox and Chrome)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box A">
        <div class="elem A"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box B">
        <div class="elem B"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box.A {
    width:175px;
    /* border:1px blue solid; */
}
.box.B {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    float:left;
    height: 175px;
    width:175px;
    /* border:1px blue solid; */
}
.elem {
    width:175px;
    height:175px;
    /* border:1px red solid; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.elem.A {
    background-image:url('http://s24.postimg.org/ua9mzwmht/arrow.png');
}
.box.A {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 3.0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
.elem.B {
    background-image:url('http://s29.postimg.org/np8utnv8j/arrow2.png');
}
.box.B {
    animation-name: rotate2;
    animation-duration: 3.0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes rotate2 {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Howdy Mathias--I think you're right about that.  Your JSFiddle didn't work though, sadly. It says there's no fiddle there.  Thanks for the help though, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 4):

It works only in WebKit browsers, becuase that's what you're telling CSS to target, for example:

```
-webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 3.0s; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
```

Firefox is not built with the WebKit engine, so you'll need to target it using the `-moz` prefix:

```
/* Target Firefox: */
-moz-animation-name: rotate; 
-moz-animation-duration: 3.0s; 
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

/* Target Webkit: */
-webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 3.0s; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

/* Target W3C Browsers: */
animation-name: rotate; 
animation-duration: 3.0s; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

Comment: He may have not included the prefixes, but is there not a problem in the fact that he is applying two transforms to one class which are therefore cancelling out?

Comment: That's another issue in itself, but the fact that he's indicated that it works in Chrome / Safari and not Mozilla...

Comment: He uses another CSS method in Chrome for the scaling, `zoom`

Comment: I'm on my tablet so I can't really check the cross browser etc. but maybe this works combining the prefixes and changing the transform issue: http://jsfiddle.net/G6rYu/4/